# Is there any way for an app to get notifications when a member has been added/removed from an MS teams channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am working on a connector that would allow users to post cards to any channel they are members of.

The idea is they would choose the info they want to post and then choose from a list of available channels which channel to post it to. To do this my app needs to know which members belong to which channels.

I think I can see how to get the list of current members when the connector is added to or removed from a channel but I do not know how to automatically find out when a member is added or removed from a channel after the connector has been added.

Is this possible or would I need to periodically poll Teams to find out if a member belongs to a channel or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a Connector, you could look at building a Bot, which has available [various events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#:~:text=Microsoft%20Teams%20sends%20notifications%20to,is%20added%20to%20a%20team). Included in these are `conversationUpdate` which contains `membersAdded` and `membersRemoved` capabilities.

Bots also have the capability of ["Pro-active" Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging), which would be the equivalent of posting cards to channels that your connector is currently doing.

Comment: Yes that sounds like a better way to do this.

Comment: Well, give it a go and of course post any questions here if you run into issues. If you feel this answer helped, please 'upvote' or 'mark as answer' so others can see it's been useful. thanks!